# Is there any way to code multiple lines in a twig file?

Tags: templating

Instead of using:

```
{% ... %}
{% ... %}
{% ... %}
```

For each line, i'd like to know if there is a way to do something like:

```
{%

...
...
...

%}
```

Answer (score 2):

You *can't* execute multiple statements inside of a single `{% %}` block.

You *can* have a single statement that is multi-line.

See here for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31111516/does-twig-support-executing-multiple-statements-inside-a-single-block